# failed to request due to wrong address, possible way to change it?

Tags: php, wordpress, amazon-ec2

Using AWS EC2, and wordpress.

When i update contents on my website, i used and connected public DNS on EC2 instance. 
When i uploaded flaticons through wordpress, i think it saved as previous Pubblic DNS like following (see also screen shot)
http://ec2-52-78-228-102.ap-northeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com

Now i changed and connected my own domain, everything has changed, 
but this thing did not change and its request url is still previous public DNS of EC2 instance, thus failed to load and can't get files.

i have changed home and siteurl in database which was like previous DNS.
but that does not change again.

Is there any other way to change its request url through coding in php files in wordpress?
just like function.php or wp-config.php.

Would you please share your idea?

[image: flaticon url]

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try a global search and replace in the database or even remove the item all together and then add it back again.

Comment: "Perhaps", is this an answer or a suggestion? Try adding a comment next time.